# flutter mapbox doesn't load style json on 9 android

Tags: android, flutter, styles, mapbox

I have problem with show mapbox on 9 android, flutter.
I loaded with style.json and there is empty map and nothing else.
on android < 9 version it works fine.. but 9 idk.
I solved problem with http on 9 android, but it steel nothing.
What I can do??

There is logs:

`E/MapboxMapBuilder(15377): setCameraTargetBounds is supported only after map initiated.
W/CrashReporter(15377): Root directory doesn't exist
W/ba.so.coba_pro(15377): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (light greylist, reflection)
W/ba.so.coba_pro(15377): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->open(Ljava/lang/String;)V (light greylist, reflection)
W/ba.so.coba_pro(15377): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->warnIfOpen()V (light greylist, reflection)
W/ba.so.coba_pro(15377): Accessing hidden field Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->theUnsafe:Lsun/misc/Unsafe; (light greylist, reflection)
V/Mbgl-ConnectivityReceiver(15377): connected - true
W/ba.so.coba_pro(15377): Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->setAlpnProtocols([B)V (light greylist, reflection)
D/EGL_emulation(15377): eglMakeCurrent: 0xec29ce00: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xebe58ad0)
I/Mbgl-EGLConfigChooser(15377): In emulator: true
D/HostConnection(15377): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xec230510, tid 15518
D/HostConnection(15377): HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2
D/eglCodecCommon(15377): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/EGL_emulation(15377): eglCreateContext: 0xec205300: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
W/LocationUpdateReceiver(15377): LocationEngineResult == null
D/EGL_emulation(15377): eglMakeCurrent: 0xec205300: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xec2036b0)
I/Mbgl    (15377): {Thread-2}[General]: GPU Identifier: Android Emulator OpenGL ES Translator (GeForce MX150/PCIe/SSE2)
D/eglCodecCommon(15377): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 3 0
W/ba.so.coba_pro(15377): Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->getAlpnSelectedProtocol()[B (light greylist, reflection)
D/HostConnection(15377): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xebe21530, tid 15414
D/HostConnection(15377): HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2
I/ba.so.coba_pro(15377): Background concurrent copying GC freed 23457(1313KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(40KB) LOS objects, 50% free, 1993KB/3MB, paused 7.542ms total 204.932ms
D/HostConnection(15377): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xec230290, tid 15409
D/HostConnection(15377): HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2
D/eglCodecCommon(15377): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 3 0
D/eglCodecCommon(15377): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 5
D/eglCodecCommon(15377): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 1 4
D/eglCodecCommon(15377): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 5
D/eglCodecCommon(15377): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 1 4
D/eglCodecCommon(15377): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 2 (2) 1 0
D/eglCodecCommon(15377): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 3 (3) 1 0
D/eglCodecCommon(15377): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 4 (4) 1 0
D/eglCodecCommon(15377): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 5 (5) 1 0
D/eglCodecCommon(15377): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 5
D/Mbgl-HttpRequest(15377): [HTTP] Cancel request http://SOME IP/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/osm:mrsk@EPSG:900913@pbf/0/0/0.pbf
D/Mbgl-HttpRequest(15377): [HTTP] Cancel request http://SOME IP/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/osm:mrsk@EPSG:900913@pbf/4/9/11.pbf
D/eglCodecCommon(15377): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 1 4
D/eglCodecCommon(15377): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 2 (2) 1 4
D/eglCodecCommon(15377): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 3 (3) 1 4
D/eglCodecCommon(15377): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 5
I/Mbgl-HttpRequest(15377): Request failed due to a connection error: Socket closed`

Answer (score 0):

The top line of your crash logs appears to be due to a bug in the Android implementation where calling setCameraTargetBounds always results in that error and no action is taking.

See the following: https://github.com/tobrun/flutter-mapbox-gl/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxgl/MapboxMapBuilder.java

On line 54.